# Limit not working

Tags: entries, craft3

I'm trying to show the next post that's not in the array of articles "completed". I have the next articles showing that haven't been completed, however i can't set a limit to just show one article. Any ideas?

here's my code

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section(['getStarted', 'rollOut', 'assessAndPrioritize', 'agreeCommit','measureSuccess']).order('stepNumber asc')  %}

    {% set test = currentUser and entry.id not in currentUser.completed.ids()  %}

    {% if test == true %}
        {{entry.title}}<br>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the limit works on the first article, but when it's "completed" and is in the entries field on the user side, it just shows blank.

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude the ids from the beginning.

```
{% set excludeIds = currentUser.completed.ids() %}
{% set entry = craft
    .entries
    .section([
        'getStarted',
        'rollOut',
        'assessAndPrioritize',
        'agreeCommit',
        'measureSuccess'
    ])
    .order({stepNumber: SORT_ASC})
    .where(['not in', 'elements.id', excludeIds])
    .one()
%}
```

`.where(['not in', 'elements.id', excludeIds])` will remove all ids in your field from your query.